# SQL: dealing with unique values in the table when UNIQUE key constraint isn't applicable

Tags: sql, mysql

What you do when you need to maintain a table with unique values when you can't use UNIQUE constraint?

For example, I use MySQL and want to map my urls to ids. So I create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE url (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, url VARCHAR(2048));
```

The problem is that mysql doesn't allow unique field bigger than 1000 bytes.
How in general do insert only if not exist in sql atomically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an extra field which would be the hash of a url e.g. md5, and make that hash field unique. You can certainly be sure that the URL is unique then, and with almost 100% certainty you can insert a new URL if it isn't already there.

It is tempting to create a table lock, however creating a table lock will implicitly commit the transaction you are working on: http://www.databasesandlife.com/mysql-lock-tables-does-an-implicit-commit/

You could create a single-row table e.g. name `mutex`, type=InnoDB, insert a row into it, and do a `select for update` on that row to create a lock which is compatible with transactions. It's nasty but that's the way I do table locks in MySQL in my applications :(

Comment: +1 for the hash idea. Even if you need to enforce utter uniqueness somehow, using a hash here will help narrow down the rows to a usable handful for a longer, slower string comparison.

Comment: Hash will definitely enforce uniqueness (the same URL goes to the same hash so would generate a unique constraint violation on the hash) but it might be that two different URLs can't be inserted if they hash to the same value. But I'm sure with a full-length hash like md5 that's really really unlikely, I mean after all `git` uses hashes to identify all commits, if hash-collisions were likely that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `not exist` condition:

```
insert  YourTable
        (url)
values  ('blah blah blah')
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   url = 'blah blah blah'
        )
```

Comment: Are you sure this is atomic, i.e. if the table is large and two such queries execute at once, is it certain that two rows won't get inserted? (This is a genuine question, I'm not saying your code is wrong, I just don't know the answer..)

Comment: @Adrian Smith: Good point, and you're probably right.  This would require serializable isolation level to be reliable (range lock), and MySQL doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to handle it is to write a trigger. The trigger is going to check  each value in the table to see whether they are equal and if yes, to raise an error. However, I don't think an URL will go beyond 1000 characters but if it does in your case, you should write a trigger to handle the uniqueness.